# How do I fight Akuma in Street Fighter X Mega Man?

Tags: street-fighter-x-mega-man

Apparently, Akuma is a secret boss character at the end of the game, as seen here:

Question is, how do I get to fight him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shoryuken reports that you need to defeat three bosses in the game with a perfect](http://shoryuken.com/2012/12/18/street-fighter-x-mega-man-secret-boss-battle/).

However, this is incorrect.  You actually have to beat *four* bosses <sup>[1](http://shoryuken.com/2012/12/18/street-fighter-x-mega-man-secret-boss-battle/#comment-742430699)</sup> <sup>[2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eu3YsZ_edCM)</sup> with a perfect in order to face Akuma.

Comment: Do the number of perfects carry over with the passwords.